# Select query to match to columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a user profile image feature. So far I am able to upload and select an image and display it, but I cannot figure out how to select the image specific to a user. My query was working (though with the issue described above) until I added the code below (//added is what I changed).

I was able to get my insert query to send the user's user_id with it, I just cannot figure out the select part.

My database for this is small, it just has `id, user_id, img`.

I want to select the `img` that is in my database that has the user's user_id. I am carrying the user_id with a session and that is what `$user_id` is.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong in my select query?

```
function getPhoto($con,$dest)
    {
        $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" ); //added

       // $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile_img` where `img` = '$dest'");
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile_img` where `img` = '$user_id'"); //added

        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            return $row;

        return 0;
    }
```

Edit: More code.

```
function getPhoto($con,$dest)
    {
        $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" ); //added

       // $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile_img` where `img` = '$dest'");
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile_img` where `user_id` = '$user_id'"); //added

        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            return $row;

        return 0;
    }


// Make sure all functions above are include here

// Get the database connection
$con        =   Connection();
// Check for post   
if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
        // Try uploading
        $upload =   UploadFile($_FILES);
        // If upload fails
        if(!$upload['success'])
            echo '<h3>Sorry, an error occurred</h3>';
        else {
                // You could add error handling here based on the results of 
                // each function's success or failure below.

                // Try to save it
                $saveToDb   =   SaveToDb($con,$upload['file']['dest']);
                // Get the profile from image name
                $profPic    =   ($saveToDb)? getPhoto($con,$upload['file']['dest']) : false; ?>


                <?php
            }
    }
?>
<img id="profile-pic" src="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? $profPic['img'] : "profile_images/default.jpg"; ?>" alt="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? "Profile Picture" : "No Picture"; ?>" />
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile" onchange="readURL(this);">
    <img width="400px" height="300px" id="file" src="#" alt="your image">
    <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: if you want `img` select it, not everything with (*)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile_img` where `img` = '$user_id'"); //added
```

Should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile_img` where `user_id` = '$user_id'"); //added
```

Because `img` column holds the `image path` and you are comparing `user id`.

Comment: Hmmm it still isn't outputting the user's image.

Comment: You should show the complete code from `selecting` up to `echoing` the results. We are not magicians here to guess your code in other part.

Comment: Does $dest have to be in it somewhere, since it is in the same line with the function name or does that not matter?

Comment: Man, you didn't even tell us what is that `$dest` for so I have no idea what it is and where to use it.

Comment: The only use of $dest is in my code I posted. It was in the code above my select query, commented out.

Comment: Remove it since you are not even using it.

Comment: Removing it did not help.

Comment: Screen shot added.

Comment: Any idea why it isn't displaying?

Comment: I actually believe the query works, just the output part at the bottom is picking the default instead of the uploaded photo...because the photo uploads and it shows after upload..just not when I reload the page. Any idea what would be wrong with the output?

Comment: Change `return $row;` into `return $row['img'];`

Comment: That didn't work. The change basically killed the insert query.

Comment: How could that be possible? The change I suggested is for `getPhoto()` function. Are you using that function in `INSERT`? Or possibly you might have change a wrong `$row`.

Comment: I believe it has to do with this line: `<img id="profile-pic" src="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? $profPic['img'] : "profile_images/default.jpg"; ?>" alt="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? "Profile Picture" : "No Picture"; ?>" />
`

Comment: Never mind, I meant the Select query. It still inserted the photo, it just didn't display it after... it didn't work.